# Progressive streaming of video in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I want to do progressive streaming of video in asp.net. I have written a code for that but still its not loading properly. Does any have idea about it.

Please have look into my code or suggest me the best way to do it. I don't want player to wait for downloading whole video and then start playing. I want to start playing right now.

Following is my code.

```
string path = "Test.mp4";
            string rootpath = Server.MapPath(Request.ApplicationPath);
            string file = string.Format(@"{0}\\{1}", rootpath, path);
            if (File.Exists(file) && file.Contains("mp4"))
            {
                FileStream filestream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                long length = filestream.Length;

                Response.AppendHeader("Content-Type", "video/mp4");
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + path + "");
                Response.AppendHeader("Content-Length", length.ToString());

                const int buffersize = 16384;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[buffersize];

                int count = filestream.Read(buffer, 0, buffersize);

                while (count > 0)
                {
                    if (!Response.IsClientConnected)
                        count = -1;
                    else
                    {
                        Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, count);
                        Response.Flush();
                        count = filestream.Read(buffer, 0, buffersize);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Best Regards,
Jalpesh

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and ended up implementing 'Range-Specific Request'. [Check this article on dotNetSlackers](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Range-Specific-Requests-in-ASP-NET.aspx). It has sample code for streaming of MP4 files. This solution works great on iPad, iPhone and Chrome!

Answer (score 1):

The `Content-Disposition` header is used to instruct the browser to offer a `Save As` dialog for the attached file. probably not the behavior you want. Did you try removing it?